# Where are Windows Phone 7 developers hanging out?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Interested in listening in on general chat by Windows Phone 7 developers. Anyone know of non-Microsoft forums? A Microsoft one would be okay unless the developers in there feel sort of obliged not to be critical.

I'm preparing to work on an infamous mobile app and whilst iPhone & Android are obviously on the list, I'm interested in whether WP7 offers anything enticing.

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the biggest and most popular forums are the [official Microsoft ones](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/windowsphone).

The next busiest (in my experience) is [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7).

If you're interested in what non-developers are saying about the platform have a look at the forums on [Backstage](http://www.windowsphone7.com/backstage/).

Comment: Thanks, I've added a tag to windows-phone-7 so I can have a look